# SQL Server - CLR function user permission

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

I have a user that is used by a program called `TicketMonitor`, which is supposed to use an user-defined CLR aggregate function in a `SELECT`, however, it appears to not have the permissions to do so.

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Die dbo-Spalte oder die benutzerdefinierte Funktion bzw. das benutzerdefinierte Aggregat 'dbo.STR_AGG' wurde nicht gefunden, oder der Name ist mehrdeutig. (4121) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Anweisung(en) konnte(n) nicht vorbereitet werden. (8180)")

Which roughly translates to command not found. However when I take the exact same statement and put it into the Management Studio application and run it as Admin, it does work, so that leads me to user rights.

When I tried granting execute permission to `TicketMonitor`, it could not find the user, maybe because it is a Database user and the function is global?

Comment: The fact that the functoin is called `dbo.STR_AGG` strongly implies your function is in a database, on the `dbo` schema. Is the function in a different database perhaps? If so, the **login** that the user is linked to will need a user created in the other database and given permission to use the function.

Comment: I think you are probably trying to grant execute permission to the wrong username. Remember, the "login" that is used to connect to the database might not carry the same name as the "user" in the database mapped to that login... How did you find the "TicketMonitor" user name?

Comment: @Larnu Yes, the function appears attached to another Database, as the program's user only appears in the Database where the Data is located and there it is listed with name "TicketMonitor" and type "Benutzer" (User), however I know it is not a Windows User.
I don't think I ever specified a Database for the function, but the Assembly appears under "master".

Comment: The user will be linked to a login, what is the login?

Comment: If you didn't specify a database when you created it, then you would have created it in whatever database you were connected to (appears `master` here). *Should* the function be in `master` though?

Comment: The user connects through DSN with UID=TicketMonitor
As for the function, as right now it is only used in one Database where the program is run, then yes it should reside in that Database and not master. How do I move it then?

Comment: @Berserker when you execute the query in SSMS and it works, what DB are you in / using? Are you in `master`? If yes, that implies that the tables are fully-qualified (i.e. include the DB name) which is why the query doesn't error. If you are in the app DB, then the assembly and UDA would have to be there as well. It is possible that the assembly was loaded into both DBs. If only in `master`, then you need to create the assembly and UDA again in the app DB (and probably drop them from `master`). And, did you try running that query in SSMS as `TicketMonitor` and not an admin?